# Vue.js in Miniprogram setup

Tags: vue.js, wechat-miniprogram

Implementation, vue.js in miniprogram.

1.create a project in vue in mp
Command: `vue init mpvue/mpvue-quickstart my-project`

1. go to file `cd my-project`
2. `npm install`
3. `npm run dev`
4. Open project by mini program `but having error about compiling`

This is the link i follow for the setup.
Link: https://mpvue.johnny.sh/

Error log

```
my-project change constantly, compiling service has not started yet...
```